# Recursive function in XCode Playground (Swift)

Tags: swift, recursion

I'm learning recursive functions in Swift, and I did the following:

```
func recursive(i: Int) -> Int {
    if i == 1 {
        return 1
    } else if i >= 2 {
        return recursive(i: i - 1) + 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

I couldn't figure out why the function above is not working. I've tested it by doing the below doing `print(recursive(10))`, which gives me an output of 10. I expected the output to be 1. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

I'm using Playgrounds on XCode 8.3.

Comment: `recursive(10) == 10` is correct. Why do you expect something else?

Comment: Yes it should be 1, but the output shows 10.

Comment: Well yes, because you're adding 1 at each recursive call, and doing 9 recursive calls – so 1 + 9 = 10

Comment: There was a typo in my first comment (fixed now). `10` is the correct output. In fact `recursive(n) == n` for all positive integers.

Comment: ... proof by [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
recursive(i: i - 1) + 1
```

… then you are in effect decrementing `i` and then incrementing it again. That cancels out and you arrive at `i` again.

Let's write down what calculation would be done for `i = 3`:

```
(3 - 1) + 1 = ((2 - 1) + 1) + 1 = (((1) + 1) + 1) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! In my mind the `+ 1` only happened once and the `(i - 1)` will keep on going until it reaches 1. I really did confused myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of printing numbers without using any loop.

The recursive functions are very useful to handle such cases.

```
func printCount( count : inout Int , limit : Int) {
    
    print(count, terminator: " ")
    count += 1  
    if count  > limit {
        return
    }
    
    printCount(count: &count , limit: limit)
}

var count = 11
let limit = 20
printCount(count: &count , limit: limit)
```

Output :  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20